# Bode plot of second-order system

Tags: transfer-function, bode-plot

I was reading about second-order systems in *Control systems engineering* by Norman Nise and I am confused by the idea that the phase at high frequencies of a second-order system is equal to 180° (check picture attached) and for the inverse of the same transfer function, the phase at high frequencies will be equal to -180°.

In fact, if we specify the interval of study of our angles as (-180,180], we should have 180° for both cases, since for both cases the transfer function will be equivalent to a negative number (-ω<sup>2</sup> or -1/ω<sup>2</sup> for me is the same as -2 and -1/2 values in phase).

What is wrong with my reasoning?

[image: Second order degree equation at high frequencies]

Comment: No - it is not correct that "the phase at high frequencies will be equal to -180°." For a second-order sysytem, the phase will APPROACH the -180deg line for rising frequencies but will never be "equal to -180 deg".

Comment: yes but that's not the question

Comment: Correct - this was not the question, but a correction to an incorrect statement.

Comment: Do you have any idea about my question?

Comment: In your post - G(s) is the denominator of a 2nd-order transfer function, correct?  And you are asking about the properties of 1/G(s) ? Why? Because such a transfer function cannot exist in reality.

Comment: yes, but for example if we simplify G(s) = s^2, the phase is not the same for G(s) and 1/G(s) however both are negative numbers

Comment: OK - now I know what your problem is. Recommendation: Do the same for a 1st-order function and you will see that the phase will approach -90deg and (inverse case) +90deg. For a 2nd- order system we will have -180deg resp. +180deg. However, in this specific case there is no difference between both. But in both cases the phase function approaches the final phase on different ways (plus and minus).

Comment: Thank you! what if we have G(s) = sin(w^2) or sin(w) do we apply the same idea of the first order system?

Answer (score 0):

> if we specify the interval of study of our angles as (-180,180] ...

Why would you? Transfer functions are basically complex numbers: \$Z=A+jB=|Z| \angle{\tan(B/A)}\$. Think about the polar representation again.

> since for both cases the transfer function will be equivalent to a negative number

No.

- For lower frequencies: \$s=j \omega_1\$ where \$\omega_1 << \omega_n\$ (i.e. way lower) therefore \$\omega_1/\omega_n<<1 \rightarrow\omega_1/\omega_n\approx0\$, so:
  $$
  G(s)=\omega_n^2\Big(\frac{s^2}{\omega_n^2}+2\zeta \frac{s}{\omega_n}+1\Big)\\
  \Rightarrow G(j\omega_1)\approx\omega_n^2((j0)^2+2\zeta\ 0+1)=\omega_n^2
  $$

So at lower frequencies the transfer function is an always-positive constant:

$$
G\approx\omega_n^2=\omega_n^2+j0=\omega_n^2 \angle{0°}
$$

- Likewise, for higher frequencies: \$s=j \omega_2\$ where \$\omega_2 >> \omega_n\$ (i.e. way higher) therefore \$\omega_n/\omega_2<<1 \rightarrow\omega_n/\omega_2\approx0\$, so:
  $$
  G(s)=s^2\Big(1+2\zeta \frac{\omega_n}{s}+\frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2}\Big) \\
  \Rightarrow G(j\omega_2)\approx(j\omega_2)^2(1+2\zeta\ 0+ 0)=(j\omega_2)^2=-\omega_2^2
  $$

So at higher frequencies the transfer function is an always-negative constant:

$$
G\approx -\omega_n^2=-\omega_n^2+j0=\omega_n^2 \angle{180°}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I am talking about 1/G and for high frequencies we say it will be equal to - 180